# Re-order the column numbers when item deleted in sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a list "Numbers". Items in this list are from 1 to 10(a column other than ID will display this number).

```
 item[1st item]["order"]=1;item[2nd item]["order"]=2;......item[10th item]["order"]=10;
```

If any item got deleted, lets say item[6th item]["order"]=6; got deleted, then the items in that list should be 1 to 9 i.e. when the item gets deleted, automatically have to order these values. Here i am using ItemDeleted Event Handler to achieve this functionality. But its not working. My code is :

```
public override void ItemDeleted (SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                string mysiteUrl = properties.WebUrl;
                SPSite mysite = new SPSite(mysiteUrl);
                SPWeb myweb = mysite.OpenWeb();
                myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList mylist = myweb.Lists["Numbers"];
                for (int i = 0; i < mylist.ItemCount; i++)
                {
                    int order = int.Parse(mylist.Items[i]["order"].ToString());
                    if (!(i + 1 == order))
                    {
                        int categoryId = int.Parse(mylist.Items[i]["ID"].ToString());
                        SPListItem item = mylist.GetItemById(categoryId);
                        item["Priority"] = i + 1;
                        mylist.Update();
                    }
                }
                myweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
            });
        }
```

I installed and activated the feature. But its not working. I dont know what going wrong here.Please help me on this issue

Comment: What do you mean by items[i]["ID"] ????

Comment: I am getting the ID of the item which violates the if condition

Comment: @Shoban, is there any other method or approach to re-order the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `Update()` on the SPListItem and not the SPList